# Mongoose groupBy multiple values

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am struggling to work with multiple groupBy with mongoose.

My collections looks like this

```
{
  salesPersonName:"Tim",
  zone:"1",
  buyerName:"Jim's Shop",
  cost:1000
},{
  salesPersonName:"Tim",
  zone:"1",
  buyerName:"Jim's Shop",
  cost:1000
},
{
  salesPersonName:"Barb",
  zone:"1",
  buyerName:"Jim's Shop",
  cost:3000
},
{
  salesPersonName:"Tim",
  zone:"2",
  buyerName:"Petra's Shop",
  cost:7000
}
```

I am trying to find the total cost by zone by buyer per salesperson.. So for each zone with buyers calculate the total cost per sales person.

Outcome:

```
Zone     buyerName      salesPerson cost

1        Jim's Shop     Tim         2000
                        Barb        3000

2        Petra's Shop   Tim         7000
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that your collection in db is named `sales`, then with proper use of schema and model:

```
const SaleSchema = new Schema({
  salesPersonName:{
    type: String
  },
  zone:{
    type: String
  },
  buyerName:{
    type: String
  },        
  cost:{
    type: Number
  }
});

const Sale = mongoose.model('Sale', SaleSchema);
```

Then you should define aggregate proper aggreaget key `_id`, with all three fields, and add new property `cost` for the sum.
The query for aggregation would look like:

```
Sale.aggregate([{$group: {
    _id:{
      zone:"$zone", 
      buyerName:"$buyerName", 
      salesPersonName:"$salesPersonName"}
    "cost":{$sum:"$cost"}}
  }, 
  {$sort: {"cost": 1}}]
);
```

Sort, of course, is not obligatory, and property names of result (salesPersonName, zone,...) can have any other name. On the other side please note that with `$` we are defining the path of the property, `$zone` represents zone property of collection `sales`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I tried this approach but I was only getting one of the possible many combinations. So I would only get :    1        Jim's Shop     Tim         2000 This line item. I am trying to figure out how to get all combinations.

Comment: Then I am pretty sure that the error is somewhere else. Please check if all documents are in DB, and corresponds to the schema. And show me the source code how do you read the result.

Comment: The documents are in the database. I can retrieve them with a normal find. I have a $match before my $group but again it pulls in all of the required documents when I groupBy one field but when I group by multiple, I only get one combination.{ '$match':
     { sellerId: '5fe47adae7acde1827c2c727',
       wasOrderCreated: true,
       activityDate: [Object] } },
  { '$group:{_id:{zone:"$zoneId",buyerName:"$buyerName",salesPersonName:"$salesPersonName"},count:{$sum:"$order.totalCost"}}}

Comment: I am sure in my answer since I have similar queries. Please write a version of MongoDB and mongoose module.

Comment: The solution works perfectly. The problem was with the way that I was printing off the results. Thank you!